# Como puedo hacer una redirección en php usando una variable

Tags: php, html, redirección

ayer buscando en internet encontré este código ya que quiero hacer una redirección a mi último video de mi canal de youtube, este código me saca el último video de mi canal pero me lo muestra en un iframe y yo lo que quiero es que me redirija al video en youtube, que tendría que hacer, pregunto pues necesito eso pero yo no se programar solo voy probando lo que encuentro y edito ciertas cosas y las hago funcionar (conozco html lo básico eso sí) peor de php no se nada

en ese caso la variable $v es la que saca el id del último video

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>InfinityxGame Last Video</title> 

    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="https://www.youtube.com/s/desktop/510f0670/img/favicon.ico">
    
</head> 
<body>
    <?php

        function youtube(){
            try{
                $youtube = new SimpleXMLElement('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCeHUAl1-X3druhpCnqhZEXA', 0, true);
                $entry = $youtube->entry[0];
                $ns = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
                $yt = $entry->children($ns['yt']);
                $v = $yt->videoId;
                echo
                
                '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$v.'?rel=0&amp;showinfo=1" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" ;></iframe>'; 
            
            } 
            catch(Exception $e){}
        }

        youtube()

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste el código como imagen? Revisa [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Answer (score 0):

En vez de imprimirlo con `echo`, puedes hacer una redirección. Estas se hacen desde HTTP cambiando el código de respuesta a 301 (permanente) o 302 (temporal, el navegador no la recordará, y es la que seguramente quieras) y añadirle la cabecera `Location` a la respuesta.

Asumiendo que `$v` es el ID del vídeo (por ejemplo, `dQw4w9WgXc`), tienes que hacer una redirección 302 a `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`, que en PHP sería más o menos tal que así:

```php
<?php
// Todo lo anterior hasta declarar $v.
// Añade la cabecera Location y usa el código 302. El true en medio es para que remplace la cabecera si ya existiera antes
header('Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$v}', true, 302);
?>
```

Ten en cuenta que este código al completo tiene que estar antes del `<html>`, es decir, arriba de todo del archivo; ya que las cabeceras deben ir antes del cuerpo (es decir, antes del HTML).

P.D. Edita la pregunta para pegar el código directamente como código, en lugar de dar una imagen; ya que en las imágenes no se puede buscar.

Comment: Hola, ando probando lo que me dijiste y ya edite la publicación y puse el código, gracias.

Comment: Como me dijiste con el header no me funcionó, gracias de todas formas por la ayuda.

Comment: @InfinityxGame ¿Puedes dar más detalles sobre por qué no funciona? ¿Qué sale en la pestaña de Red de las DevTools al visitar la página en el navegador?